# How to use countDistinct in Doctrine query builder (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am trying to count the distinct number of IDs returned for a query with his:

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov')
        ->select('c.id')
        ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
        ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
        ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
        ->where('prov.id = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->countDistinct('c.id')
        ->getQuery();
```

I am getting this error though:

```
Attempted to call method "countDistinct" on class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder" [...]
```

I have also tried

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov')
        ->select('c.id')
        ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
        ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
        ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
        ->where('prov.id = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->expr()->countDistinct('c.id')
        ->getQuery();
```

which leads to this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getQuery() on a non-object in
```

I can't get any other pointers as to how to do this differently from the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`countDistinct` is method of Expr class and COUNT DISTINCT need to be in SELECT statement so:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov');
$query = $qb
        ->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('c.id'))
        ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
        ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
        ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
        ->where('prov.id = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->getQuery();
```

should work.
Or simply:

```
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov')
        ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)')
        ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
        ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
        ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
        ->where('prov.id = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, But how come DISTINCT works as a function when used with SUM but doesn't work the same with COUNT ? Any information ?

Answer (score 3):

Proper way to use `countDistinct` in your case is:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('prov');

$query = $qb->
    ->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('c.id'))
    ->innerJoin('prov.products', 'prod')
    ->innerJoin('prod.customerItems', 'ci')
    ->innerJoin('ci.customer', 'c')
    ->where('prov.id = :brand')
    ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
    ->getQuery();
```